# What should be prefered for oral rehydration out of salts and glucose?

Tags: blood-pressure, water

What should be preferred for oral rehydration out of [salts](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.laminatorsprinters.com%2Fimages%2FORS.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.laminatorsprinters.com%2Fmedical-packaging.html&docid=qL3dS9QUWen5CM&tbnid=L3NsnJ0VRdCaKM%3A&w=400&h=300&ei=H2VEVaTeJob_UtK7gPAL&ved=0CAIQxiAwAA&iact=c) and [glucose + vitamin D](http://www.amazon.in/Glucon-D-Plain-1-kg-Jar/dp/B00I4S9Q64)?

Do both need to be taken in equal amounts? Why?

Comment: It depends on a lot of factors. First of all the reason for rehydration, that is, how did one become dehydrated in the first place (just sweating during a vigorous workout, sever vomiting or diarrhea or something else); the severity; the length of a process and likelihood of reoccurrence etc. Also, why did you tag it with blood-pressure: because of low blood-pressure due to (mild) hypovolaemia or because of ingredients unadvisable for people with high blood-pressure? I'm not sure it can be answered easily here - it has to fall in between being too broad and asking for personalised advice.